# iOS: grid in portrait / landscape orientation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I'm building a grid using UIViewTable and adding 4 items for each cel.

However, when I rotate to portrait, I need to reduce the number of items from 4 to 3. And therefore I recompute the rowsArray and I display again the table.

Is this the correct way to proceed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to use AQGridView
https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

It's an open source grid implementation that is simple and that have many samples.

otherwise, if you add items like described, you will have to redraw all cells content every time the orientation change